# Xamarin library for converting excel to pdf

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, xamarin

Are there open source libraries for free to convert xls files to pdf that work on Xamarin for Android, others than TMS Flexcel?... I am working on a xamarin project which creates xls files, and i want those to be converted to pdf files.

I've been searching the web for a long time and I haven't found anything like it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but can't you just save an Excel file as a PDF?
File > Save As > PDF